# Can I develop apps for Lion on a Snow Leopard machine?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion

Currently I am developing a Mac OS X app with XCode 3.2.5 on Mac OS X 10.6.8, the target is Release i-386. Will my app run normally on Lion?

Do I need to use XCode 4.0+?

Thanks

Comment: No - your app should run fine as it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every app built under the 10.6 SDK should, theoretically, work just as well under 10.7.

And you can use Xcode 3.X too, if you want.  But yes, I'd recommend using the latest and greatest versions of Xcode (version 4) for development.

Comment: Just don't forget to test it well on Lion. It's buggy as a VW factory.